# Why there are two running threads instead of one?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, scope, garbage-collection

So in the following:

```
public class JavaClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaClass clazz = new JavaClass();
        clazz.startCustomThread();

        clazz = new JavaClass();
        clazz.startCustomThread();
    }

    public void startCustomThread() {
        new MyThread().startThread();
    }

    private static class MyThread {
        public void startThread() {
            new Thread(() -> {
                System.out.println("In thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000 * 5);
                        System.out.println("Woke up " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
In thread Thread-1
In thread Thread-0
Woke up Thread-0
Woke up Thread-1
....
```

Since the `clazz` should be GC'd after the second instance and the first thread started in local scope of the first call to `startCustomThread()`
my question is why doesn't the first thread get terminated?

Answer (score 2):

You invoked `startCustomThread` method twice so you have started 2 Threads.

From [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) docs :

> The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute threads until either of the following occurs:
>
> 1. The exit method of class Runtime has been called and the security manager has permitted the exit operation to take place.
> 2. All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception that propagates beyond the run method.

No of those options applies to your case so the thread is still alive. This has nothing to do with garbage collection.

Comment: So basically the thread is independent of the local variable that started it? And how would I stop it if wanted to before creating the second instance of `JavaClass`?

Comment: yes. you can call interrupt on the thread as can be seen from the same linked docs.

Comment: Since you already invoke `Thread.sleep` which throws interrputed exception you could make use of it. To interrupt a thread you can use `Thread::interrupt` method which sets interrupted flag, and if your task is responsive to interruption - this is the way to go. Have a look at [`this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

Comment: @Jim your local variable `clazz` holds an instance of the class `JavaClass` which has no connection to the created threads at all. Its method `startCustomThread` creates an instance of `MyThread` on each invocation, but does not store a reference to it anywhere. So these instances of `MyThread` are eligible to garbage collection immediately after creation, but even that has no relevance to the threads, as these objects also have no reference to the actual threads. The actual threads are created in `MyThread`’s `startThread()` method via `new Thread(…)`, also without keeping a reference to them

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking specifically about why the `JavaClass` objcet is not GC'ed. it probably is (depending on VM parameters).

If you are asking why the thread spawned by that object continues to run, it is because it **creates** a new `Thread` and runs it. This will only finish when either the `run()` method finished normally, or `System.exit()` is called.

Comment: If the thread is still alive would by any way block the `JavaClass` from being GC'd?

Comment: A simple way would to be to give the `Thread` object an reference to the `JavaClass` object that created it. But think about why you want to force it to not be GC'd. If you still need it for something, your program will already reference it, so there's no need to try to stop the GC from doing its job. If you don't need it any more, it should be GC'd

Comment: I was curious if the fact that the thread remains alive is somehow associated with the `JavaClass` object hence affected its GC. I don't want to top `JavaClass` from being CGd

Comment: No, unless explicitly specified, the `Thread` is unaware of the instance of `JavaClass` that created it, and so will not prevent `JavaClass` from being GC'd

Answer (score 1):

The line `clazz = new JavaClass();` is just assigning new object to your local reference and doesn't destruct previously created object this reference was referred to. This line doesn't guarantee the object is garbage collected.

Also object's garbage collection is not necessarily related to thread's lifecycle - your thread can be interrupted or finish its execution but object still may exist in the heap and being waited for GC.

Comment: The key here to understand is that object's garbage collection and thread's lifecycle are separate mechanisms

Comment: If the thread is still alive would by any way block the JavaClass from being GC'd?

Comment: @Jim no, the running thread keeps its associated instance of `Thread` alive. It doesn’t keep the instances of `MyThread` or `JavaClass`, as there is no connection between the thread and these objects. As explained in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543974/why-there-are-two-running-threads-instead-of-one#comment101580560_57544023), whether these objects are garbage collected or not, has no relevance at all, as there is no reference between them, in neither direction. By the way, that’s how garbage collection works. It may collect objects whose existence has no relevance.

Comment: @Holger: Could you please elaborate on ` the running thread keeps its associated instance of Thread alive.`? What is `Thread` in this contexts and how is it not the same as `MyThread`?

Comment: @Jim in your code, you have the expression `new Thread(…)`. This creates an instance of the class `java.lang.Thread` which is associated with the thread which you start by invoking `start()` on exactly that object. This object will stay in memory at least as long as the thread is alive. It is not the same as your `MyThread` instance because `Thread` and `MyThread` are entirely different classes. The object of type `MyThread` is entirely irrelevant here. You could make `startThread()` a `static` method, you could move that method into the outer class and it wouldn’t make a difference.